# Online fraud (but not sure)

Tags: business, consumer-protection, fraud, evidence

This may sound funny to some, but it's very frustrating to me. So I ordered some live crabs from an online store as pets. I ordered a specific species of these crabs. The shipping info said 1 - 7 days.

They arrived after 14 days, dead, and of different species from what I ordered.

When i complain to the seller about the shipping delay, he said that 1 - 7 days is only for within Germany. I live in Greece. And for outside Germany is 14 days. But the shipping info didn't say anything about that. Just 1 - 7 days.

When I complain about the wrong species, he said that either way would be dead, so he don't see a reason to refund.
He only send me a coupon with the cost of the crabs, which i can only redeem at his store.

Does this sound right?

Do i have a legal reason to file a report to police?

I have all the required evidence.

Comment: I'm assuming you expected the crabs to be alive. I'm not sure whether it's even legal to ship living animals in a parcel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like negligence or a breach of contract or a civil consumer protection violation, not fraud or a crime. It isn't a matter for the police.

If they'd intended to defraud you, they wouldn't have send you crabs at all, even ones that ended up dying en route.

You might have a basis for a small dollar civil lawsuit for breach of contract, or for a complaint to a consumer protection agency. But failing to perform a contract for the sale of goods as agreed by delivering a product that doesn't quite conform to the agreement (yes crabs, but not the right kind), and not delivering the goods by the promised date, is not a crime unless you can prove that they intended to defraud you at the outset rather than being incompetent and drafting overly ambitious contractual terms for themselves. None of the facts provided suggest that this was the case.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.

Yes, but the shipping details were not specified. And the account for the wrong product (wrong species) did not taken.

So you think I have a legal reason to proceed with this somehow ?

Really it's not so much for the money I've lost, just this behavior is extremely frustrating.

Comment: Ok i see. You're right I cannot prove it was a fraud by these standards. But i will file that complain. After all his incompetence and negligence cost me. All I want is a refund or a new shipping. Including shipping fees. 

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: You don’t address the possible animal cruelty issue

Comment: @DaleM Not really what the question was asking.